# Should I censor a vulgar word in my psychology paper?

Tags: psychology

I have to use the word "c-nt" in a psychology paper on video games and childhood aggression. One of the essay prompts specifically asks about profanity, and so the vulgarity of this word is relevant to my argument. Would I be misrepresenting my argument if I wrote it as "c-nt"? I'm just a bit nervous about including such a widely offensive word in an academic paper.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/118428/should-i-say-write-the-n-word-in-a-quote https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/79656/how-to-handle-swear-words-in-quote-transcription

Comment: Please note that the very notion that a word itself (rather than its usage for a specific purpose) could be offensive is not agreed upon by everyone. The prevalence of this perspective is very likely culture depend, so I think a country tag might be a good idea.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Sure, but anyone from any culture can read a paper so not sure how knowing the author's native culture would affect the answer - simply that a word is considered rude in some English-speaking groups would seem to be sufficient to give rise to the question.

Comment: There is a famous article containing the word ["bullshit"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/judgment-and-decision-making/article/on-the-reception-and-detection-of-pseudoprofound-bullshit/0D3C87BCC238BCA38BC55E395BDC9999) more than a hundred times.

Comment: I prefer Louis CK's take on this, who said (paraphrasing) "you're making me say it by making me say (in my head) Oh she means 'cunt'"

Comment: @vsz There's another famous article containing the word "fucking" more than 800 times. [It's even passed peer review, I hear.](https://scholarlyoa.com/bogus-journal-accepts-profanity-laced-anti-spam-paper/)

Comment: There is a Princeton University Press philosophy tract entitled [On Bullshit](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691122946/on-bullshit).

Comment: Extending @JochenGlueck's point, I could argue that censoring a word that is essential to the topic of the paper can open the door to assuming that the author is biased against vulgarity, as opposed to openly exploring the vulgarity objectively. That's an inference, not a proof by any means. But I would suggest that this can nevertheless distract a peer's review process and bias them towards factoring this into their interpretation of your paper's content.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-: The considerations of culture are different for an author (which culture am I publishing this in?) versus a reader (which culture was this paper published in?) The question seems similar, but the response is different. For the author, it steers how they write the paper, whereas for the reader, it changes how they should _interpret_ the already written paper. This question is from the perspective of an author, not a reader, so while tangentially related, your point isn't directly relevant to OP's question.

Comment: @Flater My point wasn't really addressing anything in the OQ. I just don't see how any of the answers would differ with a country tag.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Because if it didn't differ based on culture; you're asserting that all papers are written using culture-agnostic language and concepts, which is not always strictly the case.

Comment: @flater and so you’ve downvoted all the answers that don’t discuss cultural context?

Comment: Another semi-academic word which contains profanity is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enshittification

Answer (score 39):

Actually, you are "using" the word *as a word*, no matter how you spell it. It has become common to spell certain words as you have with dash or asterisk. People understand what you mean and some will appreciate that you "soften" the expression a bit, though without changing the meaning. The concept behind the word doesn't change if you spell it with an underscore.

In academic writing, one needs to be honest, even when it seems offensive. There are some words and concepts that offend people, but if the research around them is to be honest and not suppressed, then some things need to be said. The word is offensive when used to refer to a woman or to her bodily parts, but as a word in research it is just a word.

I wouldn't object to either the use of the word spelled completely, nor the slight obfuscation. People will understand either way. And it is the understanding in research that is important.

---

Note that when referring to the word as a word, it is common and valid to put it in quotes, in which case "cunt" is (a bit) more appropriate.

I'll also note that papers intended for an international or multi lingual audience may need to be a bit more literal with such things as the understanding doesn't necessarily cross borders.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, see the update. Sorry for the poor writing.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- It seems sometimes even the justice system is too stupid to understand that distinction: https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-merseyside-43816921

Comment: To be clear, the word is also offensive when used to refer to a man ─ as it often is in the UK, at least.

Comment: @kaya3, also in the US, but it has a different meaning as a slur for a female than a male.

Comment: Just have to point out: I know of a recent incident where the n-word was used in an academic context and it lead to a reckoning.  I agree with everything everyone says about understanding and context and all of it, but do err on the side of caution!

Answer (score 19):

In most academic fields where the use/mention of epithets/vulgarity commonly arises (e.g., linguistics, law, sociology, etc.) it is common to use the full term in the relevant quotation without [bleeping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleep_censor).  Academic readers are adults and we can handle seeing epithets used in academic work, particularly when used to describe the use of epithets/vulgarity in society.  Consequently, it is perfectly acceptable to use the word "cunt" openly in your paper (without censorship) when discussing the use of profanity in video games.

As to your specific question, no, it would not misrepresent your argument if you use bleeping, so long as you make it clear to your reader that you have have added this form of censoring yourself (i.e., it was not in the original response) and so long as the censoring is done in a way that does not mislead the reader as to what epithet/vulgar term was actually used.  If you decided to go by this route you would say something like this:

> Gamer 16 responded to his gaming partner by saying, "You are such a noob [c-nt]!" (epithet censored by present author).

While the latter method is not misleading, your reader is just going to read this as "cunt" anyway,  so my own view is that it is really not a useful censoring practice.  Indeed, there has been some research that suggests that randomising interior letters of a word does not have a strong adverse effect on readability, so long as the two letters at each end are correct (see e.g., [Rawlinson 1999](https://www.newscientist.com/letter/mg16221887-600-reibadailty/)).  The same is roughly true of censoring interior letters of a word, so long as the censorship does not lead to a situation where there are multiple words in the context that could fit the censored word.  In the present case, "c-nt" has only one fitting word so it would not be misread.  Ultimately, either the censorship is going to be ineffective (if there is only one word it could be) or it is going to raise a problem of potentially misleading your reader (if the censored word could be misread as another word).

Comment: "... censoring interior letters of a word ...": I have recently read a web article where where this specific word was bleeped out as "c--t" and it was not clear from the context whether the original word was "clit" or "cunt", so I would be careful with this generalization.

Answer (score 15):

One thing you should probably be careful about is ambiguity - right now the word you have in mind is very clear to us, but in the future and across cultures (especially for foreign speakers) the exact word might not be so obvious.

Remember that over time some words have lost their offensiveness and some words became offensive - but only in certain cultures and regions. This can lead to confusion by the reader over WHICH word exactly are you talking about - especially if you'll also be mentioning other offensive words which could be mistaken for non-offensive words when bleeped.

As such, I'd strongly recommend that you write it in full **at least once** (in quotes). Afterwards, you can bleep it out if you feel like protecting sensibilities. But for academic clarity and future readers, the word(s) you're talking about should be spelled in full at least once in the paper.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is for a class, ask your teacher. If you are comfortable with it, do it in class. There are valid arguments for and against censoring, and going through those arguments could be a worthwhile teaching moment for the entire class.

Comment: I don't think the OP has specified it is for a class, rather than for publication, but in the former case, asking would be appropriate as you say.

Comment: @Buffy There is a mention of "essay prompts".

Comment: Disagree - Even if this is for a class, the student should be free to adopt standard academic convention without asking the teacher.

Comment: @Ben The point of being in a class is to learn, and the point of the teacher is to accommodate that learning. So why would a student not use that resource?

Comment: @MaartenBuis: I agree with that in general, but in this case if the teacher says, no, you cannot use vulgarity (i.e., you must censor), I think that would be an illegitimate instruction and it should be ignored.  OP has sought advice from a wide range of experienced academics on this site, so they have now already learned the standard convention/practice on this issue.

Comment: Maybe, but let's be realistic: the people on this site are not representative for academia. So even if we agree, that does not necessarily mean it is good advice. And for all the OP knows we are just random people/bots on the internet, and that is how she should treat our advice. The OP knows the credentials of her/his/their teacher, but can only hope that I am the Maarten Buis I claim to be.

Comment: Regardless, if this is indeed for a class, then it is the teacher that decides on the grades not us...

Answer (score -1):

Where the word has no specific significance, and is simply being used to express emotions, or for shock value, it may not be necessary to use it at all, and it is acceptable to use a generic placeholder as the word can usually be determined from context. Not including it will not impact on the paper's conclusions or how they are received.

> Child A: [expletive] your mom, noob

> Child B: Oh [expletive], that was so messed up.

Where the word has specific significance or has significance in specific context, for example a profanity that is a sexual or racial slur, or where it may be more offensive in specific situations, it is typically necessary to introduce the word by writing it in full, and to explain its context and any sensitivities surrounding it.

Under these circumstances, the word does not need to be repeated after its initial introduction, and can instead by substituted for an indexed entry referring to a table in your appendix.

For example

> Child A: I [exp1] your mother lasted night

> Child B: [exp2] off you stupid [exp3]

**Mild profanity**

exp1 - Hugged

**Culturally sensitive profanity**

exp2 - dance

exp3 - clodhopper

Comment: Now you got me interested: in which culture is the word "dance" considered profane?

Comment: @JochenGlueck Taliban?

Comment: @JochenGlueck perhaps they meant Dunce: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunce

Comment: @JochenGlueck I was being facetious

Comment: @SimonCrase: You mean a Taliban would write "D-cning will be punished by cutting off one leg", in order not to offend anyone? ;-)

Comment: @SimonCrase (My inner cynic is reminded a bit of the trigger warning "Drug comsumption, sexual contents, violence" that I once saw at the beginning of a TV show in a US based streaming service. It meant that somebody drank a glass of beer, a couple kissed in a bar, and about a dozen people were shot dead within a 60 minutes episode.)

Comment: @SimonCrase, smoking is now a trigger warning, and some college literature classes are now placing trigger warnings on books because of their authors even if the literature being discussed has no potentially objectionable content.

Comment: @AaarghZombies They will have a field day with Lord of the Rings then: contains descriptions of smoking, ale drinking, vertically challenged persons, and anti-Uruk bigotry.